# Why does perl regex find pattern \\label\{.*?\} but not \\ref.*?\} or \\autoref\{.*?\} in TeX Files?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

I am using perl to parse many multilingual text files. I need to change the text between two patterns:

## Desired Changes

For example, the English original version looks like this:

```
\label{whatever}
\ref{whatever}
\autoref{whatever}
```

but the stuff between `{`and `}` should be suffixed with the appropriate ISO 639 language code e.g.

```
\label{whatever_de}
\ref{whatever_de}
\autoref{whatever_de}
```

## Assumptions for Testing

Given the following files:

```
da/myfile_da.tex
de/myfile_de.tex
el/myfile_el.tex
en/myfile_en.tex
```

and each file contains:

```
\label{some_nice_thing}
\ref{some_nice_thing}
\autoref{some_nice_thing}
```

## My Approach

I can use folder names as my ISO 639 codes and create a simple loop through the files. The following should simply print the changed lines to the terminal console. I will try to explain the peculiar results I am getting by example:

### Working: `\\label\{.*?\}`

```
for f in *; do  if [[ -d $f ]]; then perl -ne "print if s/(\\label\{.*?)\}/\1_$f\}/g"  $f/myfile_$f.tex; fi; done
```

### Not Working: `\\ref\{.*?\}`

```
for f in *; do  if [[ -d $f ]]; then perl -ne "print if s/(\\ref\{.*?)\}/\1_$f\}/g"  $f/myfile_$f.tex; fi; done
```

### Not Working: `\\autoref\{.*?\}`

```
for f in *; do  if [[ -d $f ]]; then perl -ne "print if s/(\\autoref\{.*?)\}/\1_$f\}/g"  $f/myfile_$f.tex; fi; done
```

Note that `grep -Pr` works with each case (removing groups, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quoting problem. You're using double quotes for the `$f` variable, but double quotes also have other implications. In particular, they allow backslash-escaping of characters, so `\\` becomes `\` when it reaches Perl:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "print if s/(\\label\{.*?)\}/\1_$f\}/g"
print if s/(\label\{.*?)\}/\1_\}/g
```

This creates a problem with `r`, because `\r` will be seen as the return character (see [`perlrebackslash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes)) - it won't match `r`. Use single quotes instead, only opening for the variable:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 'print if s/(\\label\{.*?)\}/\1_'"$f"'\}/g'
print if s/(\\label\{.*?)\}/\1_\}/g
```

Answer (score 4):

`\\` becomes `\` in double quotes. `\\ref` becomes `\ref` which is in fact `\r` followed by `ef`. Use four backslashes:

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        perl -ne "print if s/(\\\\ref\{.*?)\}/\1_$f\}/g" $f/SystemRequirements_$f.tex
    fi
done
```

Similarly, `\a` is the BELL character (`\x07`).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is great for the extra info. I accepted muru's answer because it also answers correctly and accurately and was first. But I am sure the alternative \\\\ and \x07 will come in handy for some future readers.

Comment: Do you know why in-place editing does not work here  e.g. `perl -ei`? Obviously, this is above and beyond the original question.

Comment: @macmadness86: `-ei` is wrong, code must follow `e`.